# org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I use `mvn site`, reports are generated, but I have this exception in terminal:

```
[WARNING] Unable to process class module-info.class in JarAnalyzer File C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant (Constant.java:161)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init> (ConstantPool.java:69)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool (ClassParser.java:235)
    at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse (ClassParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.jar.classes.JarClassesAnalysis.analyze (JarClassesAnalysis.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.Dependencies.getJarDependencyDetails (Dependencies.java:259)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependenciesRenderer.hasSealed (DependenciesRenderer.java:1542)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependenciesRenderer.renderSectionDependencyFileDetails (DependenciesRenderer.java:545)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependenciesRenderer.renderBody (DependenciesRenderer.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReportRenderer.render (AbstractMavenReportRenderer.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.DependenciesReport.executeReport (DependenciesReport.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate (AbstractMavenReport.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument (ReportDocumentRenderer.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule (DefaultSiteRenderer.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render (DefaultSiteRenderer.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale (SiteMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute (SiteMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

I use eclipse. This is simple maven project without selected archetype.

What could be the problem?

More info about maven and JDK:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02- 
24T22:49:05+03:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_161, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: Are you executing mvn site from eclipse right click menu or command line

Comment: @SilverShroud I execute `mvn site` from command line

Comment: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6:site` can you try this command to see if it is related to site plugin version. After this try setting your codes compile and target level to jdk 1.8

Comment: @SilverShroud the same exception when I use `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.6:site`, JDK is already set to 1.8 everywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is caused by one of the tools in the tool chain (incorrectly) trying to load classes from the `META-INF/versions/java9` directory in the log4j-api jar.

Can you use a version of BCEL that is “multi -version jar-aware” and doesn’t try to do this?

Comment: Can you give more details about your answer? How I can use this (BCEL)? Thanks

Comment: `org.apache.bcel` is throwing the error. I think it’s a bytecode manipulation library used by the Maven site plugin. You can try forcing a later version of either Maven site or the bcel library. The underlying cause is that Log4j2 is a multi-release jar with some classes compiled for Java 9 in that directory. Tools are not supposed to load classes from there.

Comment: see http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Java8#mvn_site_fails just another java9+ incompatibility

Comment: TL;DR Update maven-site-plugin

Answer (score 1):

For all this time I have found only solution with reducing log4j2 version from `2.10.0` to `2.9.1`.

Comment: Same problem on Log4j 2.11?

Comment: @RemkoPopma yes, with log4j `2.11.0` the same problem. On `2.9.1` it works well

Answer (score -1):

to solve please try to add the following to your pom

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shared-jar</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                                <artifactId>bcel-findbugs</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
                        <version>6.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

Solved the issue for my build
```